# How to redirect HTTPS IP to domain

Tags: asp.net, iis, https, redirect

I have an asp.net website hosted on IIS 8.5 and I am using the following rule to redirect all traffic to HTTPS:

```
<rule name="HTTP/S to HTTPS Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{SERVER_PORT_SECURE}" pattern="^0$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Temporary" />
</rule>
```

This does not work when a user accesses the site using `https://192.168.0.3`

```
Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from 192.168.0.3 (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

The SSL installed is for the domain example.com and it seems the request does not reach IIS so I dont have any control over it....? I dont have control over the user to force them to use the domain url.

How do I redirect `https:/192.168.0.3` to `https://example.com`?

Comment: You need a condition to check `{HTTP HOST}`.

Comment: Can you suggest how to do that as the "Port not secure" condition would be met and no URL redirection will take place. I need to somehow add a condition for redirect if the host is IP and secure then redirect to `https://domain`

Comment: Ever figure this out...

Answer (score 4):

Trying to SSL secure a local IP url will always end up with a Certificate Error AFAIK

Read this to learn more about it: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/103524/lets-encrypt-for-intranet-websites

Edit: I don’t know a lot about IIS but found this on this matter, probably it’ll help you solve this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robert_mcmurray/2013/11/15/how-to-trust-the-iis-express-self-signed-certificate/

Comment: I think you are correct, even facebook doesnt have a redirect for `https://157.240.22.35` to `https://facebook.com`. Same with google `https://172.217.5.110/`

Comment: Thing is, a trusted certificate vendor can’t verify the validation of your local Domain because it can’t reach it via a public dns. The only real option I can think of is installing the certificate(s) as trusted certificates on the users machine(s). But then again IIS is not my domain. Good look!

Comment: @VaibhavGarg neither of those IPs are private so aren't relevant. You can definitely put certs on IPs, just not private ones e.g https://1.1.1.1/ .

Answer (score 1):

Given the HTTPS private IP never would have worked (you can't get a valid cert for it), I assume you've got here because you've got a global redirect from `http://192.168.0.3` to `https://192.168.0.3`. Just fix that redirect so it goes from `http://192.168.0.3` directly to `https://example.com`.

Comment: Yes, I have that going already. the 192 IP is just an example. The real IP is for a production site accessible by public. So the main issue is that `https://IP` does not reach IIS so I have no control over its redirect. Maybe something at OS level can be done...

Comment: If it's not reaching the site due to a cert error, you need to get a cert and install it.

Comment: This answer made me realized how stupid i am playing with the .htaccess file. +1

Answer (score -1):

What you could do is create another website in IIS and bind the IP address to it. Then in that website either create a single `Default.aspx` page with a redirect to the correct domain.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%
    Response.Redirect("https://example.com");
%>
```

Or just a `web.config` file with the url rewrite

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://example.com" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I have tried this and it seems the browser just stops as soon as it gets the certificate for the domain which doesnt match with the IP based url originally entered so IIS doesnt get a chance to redirect.. atleast that is what I understand

Comment: This won't work as you can't serve a valid cert on the private IP without modifying the cert store in every browser that connects ahead of time.